# How to test fastest mirror

Tags: linux, curl, xargs

I'm currently using `xargs -n 1 -P 24 curl -s -w '%%{url_effective}\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null < mirrors.txt` to test the response time for each mirror. I want to be able to terminate all instances of `curl` once the first/fastest one completes. This might not be the best way to do it, so I am open to other solutions that get my desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in the context of downloading packages from a repository ?  In many cases the package manager offers the means to detect and use the relevant fastest mirror.

Comment: Also, consider using curl `-r` option to just download a part of the file from each mirror, in order to avoid invoking some sort of DoS attack against the estate of mirror servers ?

Comment: Unless you're going to download a lot (and then things may change, making the chosen mirror slow), it's probably faster to just download from a random mirror.

Comment: This isn't about downloading from the package manager.

I will be downloading a lot. These mirrors are slow and do go down. The reason for my question is because I want to find the quickest mirror and automatically update an environment variable that will store the link to the fastest mirror. Sometimes it takes minutes for the last mirror to send a response so the automation script becomes useless because I could do it faster manually.